# What is $-1$ to the power of a fraction?

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation

If I have any negative number (does not have to be $-1$), how would I determine that value to the power of $1/2$?

I learned that $x^\frac{1}{2}$ is equal to $√x,$ so wouldn't $-1^\frac{1}{2}$ be equal to $i$? Why does the calculator return $-1$?

Comment: What you "learned" left off a critical fact: $x^\frac12 = \sqrt{x}$ **for all nonnegative real numbers $x$**.

Comment: It is quite incorrect to write $-1^n$ if you mean $(-1)^n.$ The expressions $-5^2$ and $(-5)^2$ refer to two different numbers: one of them is $-25$ and the other is $+25. \qquad$

Comment: Does $-1^{\frac12}$ mean $-(1^{\frac12})$ or $(-1)^{\frac12}$ to you?

Comment: If your calculator pays attention to parentheses, it may be calculating $-(1^{\frac 12})$ instead of $(-1)^{\frac 12}$...

Comment: I personally think $(-1)^{1/2}$ (along with $\sqrt{-1}$) is a rather useless expression. Allowing it yields comparatively little utility, but opens up a nasty door of multivalued functions and arithmetic rules that suddenly don't work.

Comment: The calculator, and standard math notation, interpret "$-1^{\frac 12} = -(1^{\frac 12})=-\sqrt{1}=-1$".  What you intend needs to be written as $(-1)^{\frac 12} = ???$.  You can try punching that into a calculator but keep in mind ... IT'S AN EFFING MACHINE... it only does what it's programmed to do.  It does not think.  Complex analysis where $i^2 = -1$ is a ..er, complex... study and will require many caveats that simply saying "$(-1^{\frac 12})=\sqrt{-1}=i$" oversimplifies way too many issues than i can address in a comment.

Comment: If you read the fine print of you mathematical contract it says that **for a positive $b$** then $b^{\frac 1n}$ is the unique *real* number $c$ so that $c^n=b$.  From there it is a subclause that $b^{\frac mn}$ is the number $c$ so that $c^n=b^m$.  The definition for the meaning of $b^x$ when $x\not\in \mathbb Q$ is in an entirely different section of the contract and the definition for when $b$ is not positive is only contained in the optional extended warranty, completely different section.

Comment: yeah nevermind it was just a calculator error lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not to worry too much about all the notation, and look at this page, [DLMF 6.6](https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.6), from an online reference of special functions.

Notice that in several items we have "$(-1)^n$" and also one "$(-1)^{n-1}$".  These have parentheses in order to accurately express what is meant, a power of $-1$.  Without the parentheses, the [order of operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) specifies that the power would happen before the negation, so one would not get a power of $-1$.

If one is typing this on a calculator, there are a number of common errors.

```
-1^1/2     = -((1/1)^2) = -1
-1^(1/2)   = -(1^(1/2)) = -1
(-1)^1/2   = ((-1)^1)/2 = -1/2
```

If you want the quantity $-1$ raised to the power $1/2$, you need to enter

```
(-1)^(1/2)
```

Depending on your calculator (and possibly on a mode setting on your calculator) evaluation of this expression will produce an error (some form of [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) error, since $-1$ is not in the domain of the real [square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root) function) or a result that is equivalent to the complex number $0 + 1\mathrm{i}$ produced by the [complex square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Square_roots_of_negative_and_complex_numbers) function.

Answer (score -1):

There are two square roots of $-1$ and no reason to prefer one of them to the other. You can call one of them $i$ and the other $-i,$ or switch those two roles around so that the one that you called $-i$ before is now $+i$ and vice-versa, and nothing changes. And there are three cube roots of $-1,$ one of those being $-1$ itself and the others $(1\pm i\sqrt3)/2.$ If you want $(-1)^x$ to change in a smooth way as $x$ changes, then you'll need to pick one of those latter two to be the value of $(-1)^{1/3}.$ And what then is $(-1)^{2/3}\text{?}$ Should it be the square of $(-1)^{1/3} = \sqrt[3]{-1}= -1\text{?}$ That would make it $+1.$ Or should it be the square of $(1+i\sqrt3)/2,$ which is $(-1+i\sqrt3)/2\text{?}$